# Javascript - call new on undefined object

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am using require.js to organize my js:

```
define([
   'underscore',
   'sylvester',
   'glUtils',
   'GLFacade',
   'Item',
   'Attribute',
   'Buffer',
], function(
   _,
   sylv,
   glUtils,
   GLFacade,
   Item,
   Attribute,
   Buffer
) {
   "use strict";
   function Sprite() { this.init.apply(this, arguments); }

   _.extend(Sprite.prototype, {
      init: function(prog, img, viewPort) {
         this._frameNum = 0;
         this._framesPerAnimation = 4;
         this._prog = prog;
         this._viewPort = viewPort;
         this._img = new ImageWrapper(img);

         //...other initialization stuff...
      },

      //...other methods...

   });

   return Sprite;

});
```

but I consistently run into the error that I forget to add a module to the top of the file. Above I've forgotten to add `ImageWrapper` to my dependencies. When I do this, my code silently fails with no error messages, even though `ImageWrapper` is `undefined`. If I try to log `console.log(ImageWrapper)` I do indeed get an error.

Why doesn't the constructor call to `new ImageWrapper(img)` fail with an error? And is there something similar to `"use strict;"` that I can use to increase the error information during development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could lint your code using a tool like http://jshint.com/ - you will get something like:

```
One undefined variable
27  ImageWrapper
```

Depending on your setup there are different ways to automate this, some editors have built this in or plugins can extend this functionality. There also is a command line version on npm if you want to run jshint manually: https://npmjs.org/package/jshint

Your code should throw an error but only if you instantiate a `new Sprite`.

When I try to simplify your code like this

```
define('Sprite', ['underscore'], function(_) {
  'use strict';

  function Sprite() {
    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  _.extend(Sprite.prototype, {
    init: function() {
      this._foo = new DoesntExist();
    }
  });

  return Sprite;
});

require(['Sprite'], function(Sprite) {
  var sprite = new Sprite();
});
```

it throws a ReferenceError as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can hook that up. What's strange is I am not getting any errors, even when I instantiate `new Sprite`.

Comment: Can you try to run my simplified version and see if it throws an error? Maybe I got something wrong since I have never used requirejs before.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your example helped me find the problem. The problem was that all my code occurs inside the `onFulfilled` function of a [Q.spread](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisespreadonfulfilled-onrejected) and I didn't define an error handler. I added a `.catch()` at the end and that fixed it. It was throwing an error before but Q was just swallowing it.

Comment: I'm glad you found it. I guess issues like these are the downside of promises and async...